# jquery.ajax to PHP fails when I use ECHO in my PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

this is the 1st time I try to use AJAX - my website needs to call a PHP during runtime when the user leaves a specific form field (VIN). I pass the value of this field to a PHP function for validation and processing. Then PHP should return 3 values for 3 different form fields.
This is my problem: I won't get the 3 values back into my javascript.

Each time when I use ECHO json_encode in my php the AJAX call crashes and the console shows "VM7190:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y in JSON at position 0(…)".

If I put any other simple ECHO in my PHP the AJAX call would return with an error.

If I remove each ECHO from my PHP the AJAX call returns as success but the returning data is NULL.

It would be so great if I could get a solution for this problem here.

If anybody would like to test the site - this is the url: [mycarbio](http://mycarbio.livedemo.click/test-form/)

Thank you very much.

This is my AJAX call:

```js
function decode_my_vin(myvin) {

alert("in decode_my_vin");
dataoneID  = '123';
dataoneKEY = 'xyz';

jQuery.ajax(
    {
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/vin-decoder.php',
 dataType:'json',
    data: { 
   'value1_VIN': myvin,
   'value2_ID': dataoneID,
   'value3_KEY': dataoneKEY,
   'value4_Year': ' ',
   'value5_Make': ' ',
   'value6_Model': ' '
    },
// async: false,
 success: function(response) {
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
   alert("success returned: " + obj); 
      document.getElementById("fld_7290902_1").value = "2015";
      document.getElementById("fld_1595243_1").value = "Ford";
      document.getElementById("fld_7532728_1").value = "Focus";
   return;
  },
 error: function() { alert("error in der jquery"); }
    });
}
```

And this is my PHP

```html
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

 $resultYear = '2010';
 $resultMake = 'Ford';
 $resultModel = 'Focus';
 
    $vinResult = array("Year: ", $resultYear, "Make: ", $resultMake, "Model: ", $resultModel);

 echo json_encode($vinResult);
?>
```

Comment: First, put both your name and the variable in double quotes - like this: `array("Year:"=>"$resultYear","Make:"=>"$resultMake","Model:"=>"$resultModel"); (`=>` is the key=>value-assignment, not `,`).

Comment: You dont need the line with `jQuery.parseJSON(response)` just assign the values as you called in your array in PHP, `response.Year`, etc.

Comment: Thank you both. I removed parseJSON and changed the way I assigned my values to the key in PHP. Worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be your only problem, but you should try using an associative array when rendering the JSON:

```
$vinResult = array(
  'Year' => $resultYear, 
  'Make' => $resultMake,
  'Model' => $resultModel
);
```

Currently you are combining your property names and values.

Comment: I believe this sums up your problem.. +1